# Failing Mailer Test - ActionView::Template::Error: Missing host to link to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I currently have a failing test for one of my mailers and can't figure out what's causing it. I've tried some other solutions on stack like, adding `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = '???'` to the config environment files but to no avail. Here is the error output form the terminal

```
Error:
OrderMailerTest#test_shipped:
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `protect_against_forgery?' for #<#<Class:0x007f97fe5f0080>:0x007f97ff82b790>
    app/views/line_items/_line_item.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_line_items__line_item_html_erb__1698223746397690403_70145401700580'
    app/views/order_mailer/shipped.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_order_mailer_shipped_html_erb__790900287724335052_70145401782860'
    app/mailers/order_mailer.rb:23:in `shipped'
    test/mailers/order_mailer_test.rb:14:in `block in <class:OrderMailerTest>'


bin/rails test test/mailers/order_mailer_test.rb:12
```

order_mailer_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class OrderMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
  test "received" do
    mail = OrderMailer.received(orders(:one))
    assert_equal "Pragmatic Store Order Confirmation", mail.subject
    assert_equal ["dave@example.org"], mail.to
    assert_equal ["depot@example.com"], mail.from
    assert_match /1 x Programming Ruby 1.9/, mail.body.encoded
  end

  test "shipped" do
    mail = OrderMailer.shipped(orders(:one))
    assert_equal "Pragmatic Store Order Shipped", mail.subject
    assert_equal ["dave@example.org"], mail.to
    assert_equal ["depot@example.com"], mail.from
    assert_match /<td>1&times;<\/td>\s*<td>Programming Ruby 1.9<\/td>/, mail.body.encoded
  end
end
```

and my config files.

development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

      # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
      # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
      # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
      config.cache_classes = false

      # Do not eager load code on boot.
      config.eager_load = false

      # Show full error reports.
      config.consider_all_requests_local = true

      # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
      if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
        config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

        config.cache_store = :memory_store
        config.public_file_server.headers = {
          'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=172800'
        }
      else
        config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

        config.cache_store = :null_store
      end

      # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
      config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

      config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

      # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
      config.active_support.deprecation = :log

      # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
      config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

      # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
      # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
      # number of complex assets.
      config.assets.debug = true

      # Suppress logger output for asset requests.
      config.assets.quiet = true

      # Raises error for missing translations
      # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

      # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
      # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
      config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker

      # Don't actually send emails
      config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

      # Alternate configuration example using gmail
      config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
      config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
        address:        "smtp.gmail.com",
        port:           587,
        domain:         "domain.of.sender.net",
        authentication: "plain",
        user_name:      "dave",
        password:       "secret",
        enable_starttls_auto: true
      }
    end
```

production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "depot_#{Rails.env}"
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

test.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
  # test suite. You never need to work with it otherwise. Remember that
  # your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
  # and recreated between test runs. Don't rely on the data there!
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Do not eager load code on boot. This avoids loading your whole application
  # just for the purpose of running a single test. If you are using a tool that
  # preloads Rails for running tests, you may have to set it to true.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Configure public file server for tests with Cache-Control for performance.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = true
  config.public_file_server.headers = {
    'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=3600'
  }

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates.
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment.
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

Any advice would be appreciated!!

Comment: Which version of rails are you using?

Comment: I'm on version 5.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to a helper that only your mailers will use and see if this works:

```
def protect_against_forgery?
      false
 end
```

Comment: Sorry I accidentally pressed enter and can't edit my comment.
I added the line `require 'helpers/validation_helper'` to order_mailer_test.rb. And created a helper called validation_helper.rb in the helpers folder. With the code above within `module ValidationHelper`